# Make parent class return a child from class factory

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I have a parent class, and I want to make it so that I can return its children from a class factory, here's some code:

```py
class Super:
    def __new__(cls, t):
        return class_factory(t)

# Because I need a Super class with some custom state
def class_factory(t):
    class Sub(Super):
        t = t

        def __init__(self):
            pass

    return Sub

assert isinstance(Super(1)(), Super)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 't'
```

I get that its trying to call `Super`'s `__new__` method. Is there a way to skip that, or at least preserve the type signature in a way that doesn't cause infinite recursion? (I *need* to preserve the type signature of both classes).

Comment: If `Super` is supposed to be a class factory, it should be a [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-metaclass). Not a parent class.

Comment: Calling a class should return an instance of that class. Not another class. Why do you think you have to break this fundamental expectation of OOP? Do you have a *very* good reason?

Comment: Basically, for a metaclass, I'd have to do `isinstance(type(x), metaclass)` instead of `isinstance(x, superclass)`.

Comment: How about something like `isinstance(Meta(1)(), Super)`? Any problems with that?

Comment: I can't instantiate using `Super` that way, I already have that working. I prefer `Super(1)` to be `Meta(1)()`, and `Super in type(Meta(1)()).__bases__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code I get a different error, namely:

`NameError: name 't' is not defined`

on the `t = t` line.

This is because the body of a `class` statement is executed in its own namespace, so the `t` in the enclosing namespace isn't in scope as it usually is. Another issue is that your `__new__()` doesn't call its base class' `__new__()`.

Lastly, the call to `Super(1)()` is wrong. Calling a class returns an instance of the class (or in this case, an instance of a subclass).

To fix all of these problems and get your code to work, you could need to do it like this:

```
class Super:
    def __new__(cls, t):
        subclass = class_factory(t)   # Create subclass.
        return super().__new__(subclass)  # Using base class method to avoid recursion.


def class_factory(t_arg):
    class Sub(Super):
        t = t_arg

        def __init__(self, t):
            pass

    return Sub

# Note Super(1) returns an instance of the subclass.
assert isinstance(Super(1), Super)
```

**Update:**

Based on your comments, I would suggest using a class decorator instead. 
— something like this:

```
def inject(name, value):

    def decorator(cls):
        setattr(cls, name, value)
        return cls

    return decorator


@inject('t', 42)
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.t)


assert isinstance(Test(), Test)  # -> 42
```

This doesn't create subclasses, however you could change the name of the decorated class if you wished.

Comment: Excellent explanation! One minor comment, could you change `object` to `super()`?

Comment: Is there a way to do this while keeping the `Sub` signature the same?

Comment: Thanks. I think generally `__new__` and the class constructor need to have the same signature, but there may be a workaround. I'll look into it.

Comment: I can't think of a way to avoiding it using this approach. It could be done by defining a custom metaclass (instead of using the default one, `type`) which is what happens here.

Comment: I currently just resorted to checking and subsequently discarding the `t` argument.

Comment: That would work. See update for another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
class Super:
    def __new__(cls, t):
        return class_factory(t)

def class_factory(t):
    class Sub(Super):
        _tp = t
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            instance = object.__new__(cls)
            return instance

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            pass

    return Sub
```

To avoid the error you need to define your custom `__new__()` method in `Sub`, so you can avoid to recursively call `Super`'s `__ new__()` method.
The type is preserverd in the `_tp` class attribute of `Sub`.

With this code, the `assert isinstance(Super(1)(), Super)` does not raise any error.

#### EDIT after comment

Fixed `*args` and `**kwargs`. The rule is that whatever argument signature you have in `Sub.__init__()` must be used also by `Sub.__new__()`. For example, if you need `Sub.__init__(self, a, b)` then you should have `Sub.__new__(cls, a, b)`.

Comment: This doesn't work: `object.__new__() takes no arguments`, and if I change it to `object.__new__(cls)` then `__init__` signature has to change, which I don't want to do.

Comment: I fixed my answer. But I have to say, the class decorator in @martineau 's answer is the most elegant solution in my opinion.